# How to calculate the specific rate among three classes?

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the survival rate with the data frame 'Titanic'.

I have filtered a object named "Male_adult_passengers", whose vector 'Class' includes three ranks.

There is another column recording the condition of survival ('yes' or 'no')

And I would like to get the survival rates within different classes and compare them.

I applied the dplyr package and tried coding as:

```
Male_adult_passenger %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(S_rates = count(Survived = 'Yes')/count(Survived))
```

But only turned out an error message:

```
Error in group_vars(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

What does this message mean? And how can I get the survival rate needed?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, next time please provide a reproducible example. You can easily do that for example with `dput(Male_adult_passenger)`.

In any case, that error comes from using the assignment `Survived = 'Yes'`, instead of the comparison `Survived == 'Yes'`.

Try fixing that, but my guess is that `count` will be troublesome. If it doesn't work, try:

```
Male_adult_passenger %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(S_rates = sum(Survived == 'Yes')/n())
```

If that still does not work, please provide a sample by editing your question and I'll be glad to look it further.

Answer (score 0):

Before I provide any solution, it is important to know how to traceback the error. The error report provides at which step the issue takes place.
I picked up the publicly available titanic dataset to create the dataframe which I assume resembles your dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
titanic<-read.csv('titanic.csv')
Male_adult_passenger<-subset(titanic,Sex=='male')
Male_adult_passenger$Survived<-ifelse(Male_adult_passenger$Survived==0,"No","Yes")
Male_adult_passenger$Survived<-factor(Male_adult_passenger$Survived)
```

While executing your codeblock, the issue was with count(Survived = 'Yes'). The logical comparison syntax was not correct as mentioned by mgiormenti. Once you correct the logical comparison, you'll get an error that count is not an applicable method for your object class 'Survived'. Count doesn't work with dplyr. Best alternatives are sum, length and n()
n() counts the number of observations in your grouped object class.

```
Male_adult_passenger %>%
  group_by(Pclass,Survived) %>%
  summarize(n())
```

```
Pclass Survived  n()
<int>   <chr>    <int>
1        No       77        
1        Yes      45        
2        No       91        
2        Yes      17        
3        No       296       
3        Yes      47
```

Alternative of n() for character columns is the length function. What you need is probably length of the Survived column where Survived=='Yes', Survived[Survived=='Yes']

```
Male_adult_passenger %>%
  group_by(Pclass) %>%
  summarize(S_rates=length(Survived[Survived=="Yes"])/n())
```

```
Pclass S_rates
<int>  <dbl>
1   0.3688525           
2   0.1574074           
3   0.1370262
```